# attn_output_weights in MultiheadAttention

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, attention-model

I wanna know if the matrix of the `attn_output_weight` can demonstrate the relationship between every word-pair in the input sequence.
In my project, I draw the heat map based on this output and it shows like this:
[image]

However, I can hardly see any information from this heat map.
I refer to other people's work, their heat map is like this.  At least the diagonal of the matrix should have the deep color. [image]

Then I wonder if my method to draw the heat map is correct or not (i.e. directly using the output of the `attn_output_weight` ) If this is not the correct way, could you please tell me how to draw the heat map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your range of values is rather limited. In the target example the range of values lies between `[0, 1]`, since each row represents the softmax distribution. This is visible from the definition of attention:

[image]

I suggest you normalize each row / column (according to the attention implementation you are using) and finally visualize the attention maps in the range `[0, 1]`. You can do this using the arguments `vmin` and `vmax` respectively in matplotlib plottings.

If this doesn't solve the problem, maybe add a snippet of code containing the model you are using and the visualization script.